# Search form with a drop down list

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a search form where I have to search by Category which is a drop down list.There are 2 tables called members and categories.In categories table there are two fields as ID and Name(this Name field stores the name of the category like bank,hospital..).members table there is a field called Category which has the ID of the category which is same as the categories table ID value(Category field in members table is a foreign key).

Here is the code for the drop down list

```
<?php if($_GET['level']==2){ ?>
        Category<select name="Cat" style="display:inline-block">
        <option></option>
        <?php $rs=mysql_query("SELECT ID,Name FROM categories ORDER BY Name"); 
        while($rc=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rc[ID]; ?>" 
            <? echo $_POST['Cat'];?>
            <?php if($_POST['Cat']==$rc[ID])
                     echo 'selected'; ?> >
            <?php echo $rc['Name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
        <?php } ?>
```

I have several palces where I don't  understand in this code.

1. What's the use of `value="<?php echo $rc[ID]"`.It is supposed to echo what I just input in the text box right?But $rc[ID] refers to a value from 1,2,3,4,5 but for the values in the drop down list it doesn't show numbers.So why echo this?
2. `$_POST['Cat']` doesn't refer to anything in the database right because I don't have such field.It has to do with `<form name="Cat">`. How does this `$_POST['Cat']` gets values which should be integers in order to see a matching with `$rc[ID]`.But how does it get integer values because all I am inputting is from the drop down list a particular name.
3. What's the use of "`echo selected`"?Is it there to be used when a matching is found then the option tag becomes `<option selected>` so that this value pops to the top of the list

Answer (score 0):

1. `value=<?php echo $rc[ID]` this use only for the database when you
   submit the form this value is stored to your database table Ex.
   `<option value='1'>Display Value</option>` here 1 is store to db and
   display value used to display value is front end.
2. `$_POST['Cat']` right this is not referring any database value this
   value is happens only when you submit the form In your case you have
   to write #rc[Name] then only display the drop down.
3. the use of `echo selected` is that when your condition match then
   only first time in the drop down list value is selected
   automatically.

**UPDATE:**

`<option value="<?php echo $rc[ID]; ?>` gives integer value because your are getting post value of select drop down list 
`$rc[ID]` gives the value because you are using to fetch data from database like `SELECT ID,Name FROM categories ORDER BY Name`

May this help you

Comment: How can $_POST['Cat'] get a integer value to match that of $rc[ID].And there's no table specified for the **value=<?php echo $rc[ID]** to be stored.I don't think it goes to the database.